# Firebase database trigger - get database object from snapshot

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am writing a Firebase database trigger function to push notifications to several users. For consistency I would like to batch all write operations, but I am having trouble creating the batch.

How can I get a reference to the database from data snapshot?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')

exports.onNoteCreate = functions
.region('europe-west1')
.database
.ref('/notes/{noteId}')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
  //Get a reference to the database - this does not work!
  const db = snapshot.getRef()
  ...
  const notificationObject = {"test": true}
  //Run database batched operation - prepare batch
  let batch = db.batch()
  peopleToAlert.forEach((personId, index) => {
    //Write notification to all affected people
    const notificationId = db.ref().push()
    const batchWrite = db.collection(`/notifications/${personId}/notes`).doc(notificationId)
    batch.set(batchWrite, notificationObject)
  })
  //Commit database batch operation
  return batch.commit().then(() => {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => (resolve()))
  }).catch( (err) => {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => (reject(err)))
  })
})
```

I have also tried the approach below to no avail

```
const db = admin.database()
```

Any clarification much appreciated! Kind regards /K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the root Reference of the Database from a [`DataSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot), do as follows:

```
const snapshotRef = snapshot.ref.root;
```

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#ref and https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference.html#root

---

**HOWEVER**, you are triggering your Cloud Function with a **Realtime Database trigger** while the concept of batched write is for **Firestore**, which is a different database service. So you cannot use the root Reference of the Realtime Database to create a Firestore [`WriteBatch`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.WriteBatch).

So if you want to create a [`WriteBatch`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.WriteBatch) within your Cloud Function you need to get it from the Admin SDK, as follows:

```
let batch = admin.firestore().batch();
```

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.firestore

Comment: Many thanks @Renaud! I accidentally read the Firestore documentation. :) Will use snapshot.ref.root for other purposes !